# Dissolve Polygons using R / join specific polygons

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, spatial-join

I have data in shapefile format :: [UK_boundaries](http://census.edina.ac.uk/ukborders/easy_download/prebuilt/shape/infuse_dist_lyr_2011_clipped.zip) 
 I am new to R and Spatial data as well,  I am trying to join some areas to be as one area no line(s) between them. Based on my search I understand that  **unionSpatialPolygons** function dissolves polygons but when  I tried to use it  I got error: 
**Error:** TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 162544.73551388 516922.55880385998 at 162544.73551388 516922.55880385998

```
libs <- c("rgdal", "maptools", "gridExtra", "rgeos", "raster")
lapply(libs, require, character.only = TRUE)

    LA <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "infuse_dist_lyr_2011_clipped")
    IDs <- LA$geo_code

IDs[IDs %in% c("95DD","95II","95QQ","95EE","95RR","95UU","95TT","95CC","95BB")] <- c("95AA","95GG","95HH","95JJ","95JJ","95JJ","95KK","95OO","95XX")

LA_new <- unionSpatialPolygons(LA, IDs)
```

In summary I want areas of the same colour shown here to be joined.

[image: NIR_Geos]

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your error. A current workaround is to use [`gpclib`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpclib/index.html) (free for non-commercial use) instead of [`rgeos`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgeos/index.html):

```
# install.packages("gpclib")
library("gpclib")
gpclibPermit()
# [1] TRUE
# Warning message:
# In gpclibPermit() :
#  support for gpclib will be withdrawn from maptools at the next major release

LA_new <- unionSpatialPolygons(LA, IDs, avoidGEOS=TRUE)
```

Comment: That is very interesting. Do you know why/how gpclib avoids this error. I get that same error in Postgis (also from GEOS, obviously), quite often on large union jobs. There are workarounds, but it is annoying.

Comment: `gpclibPermit()` returns a warning message saying "support for gpclib will be withdrawn from maptools at the next major release" - seems like it won't be much longer before this very nice workaround is doomed to fail...

Comment: @rcs Thanks for you effort, I could not install "gpclib", I get Installing package into ‘\\hudson/jpdg26/My_Documents/R/win-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

   package ‘gpclib’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gpclib’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)

although according to its description it should be installed for R( > 2.14.0)[gpclib](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpclib/index.html)

Comment: okay, you are using windows :/ See this http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/r-release/ReadMe

Comment: @rcs I try to force gpclib works in R but I could not! Is there any other way to dissolve polygons rather than using gpclib?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm a year late but I still want to post the answer so maybe it can help others later.

The error message is self-explanatory -- there's topology error (Self-intersection) in your shapefile. You can use `gIsValid()` function in `rgeos` to reproduce the error and detect any other topology error in your shapefile.

As for the fix, I would suggest to remove the topology error by editing shapefile using QGIS or ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

An Interesting way to avoid/fix TopologyException errors was proposed by @hrbrmstr [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/r-solution-for-topologyexception-input-geom-1-is-invalid-self-intersection-er#163480): forcing a **zero-width buffer**. 
So try this before applying `unionSpatialPolygons`. In the given example of @Iman, maybe something like: (*I didn't test it*)

```
LA_2 <- gBuffer(LA, byid=TRUE, width=0)
LA_new <- unionSpatialPolygons(LA_2, IDs)
```