# Getting TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid which is due to self-intersection in R?

Tags: r, polygon, rgeos, self-intersection

The 'TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid' self-intersection error which arises from invalid polygon geometries has been widely discussed. However, I haven't found a convenient solution on the web that solely relies on R functionality.

For instance, I have managed to create a 'SpatialPolygons' object from the output of `map("state", ...)` following Josh O'Brien's nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751497/latitude-longitude-coordinates-to-state-code-in-r/8751965#8751965).

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)

map_states = map("state", fill = TRUE, plot = FALSE)

IDs = sapply(strsplit(map_states$names, ":"), "[[", 1)
spydf_states = map2SpatialPolygons(map_states, IDs = IDs, proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

plot(spydf_states)
```

[image: states]

The problem with this widely applied dataset is now that self-intersection occurs at the point given below.

```
rgeos::gIsValid(spydf_states)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In RGEOSUnaryPredFunc(spgeom, byid, "rgeos_isvalid") :
  Self-intersection at or near point -122.22023214285259 38.060546477866055
```

Unfortunately, this problem prevents any further use of 'spydf_states', e.g. when calling `rgeos::gIntersection`. How can I solve this issue from within R?

Comment: If you zoom in around that point: `plot(spydf_states, xlim=c(-122.1,-122.3),ylim=c(38,38.1))` you'll see there's no "seemingly" about it - there's a self-intersection.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Using a zero-width buffer cleans up many topology problems in R.

```
spydf_states <- gBuffer(spydf_states, byid=TRUE, width=0)
```

However working with unprojected lat-long coordinates can cause `rgeos` to throw warnings.

Here's an extended example that reprojects to an Albers projection first:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

load("~/Dropbox/spydf_states.RData")

# many geos functions require projections and you're probably going to end
# up plotting this eventually so we convert it to albers before cleaning up
# the polygons since you should use that if you are plotting the US
spydf_states <- spTransform(spydf_states, 
                            CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5 +lon_0=-96"))

# simplify the polgons a tad (tweak 0.00001 to your liking)
spydf_states <- gSimplify(spydf_states, tol = 0.00001)

# this is a well known R / GEOS hack (usually combined with the above) to 
# deal with "bad" polygons
spydf_states <- gBuffer(spydf_states, byid=TRUE, width=0)

# any bad polys?
sum(gIsValid(spydf_states, byid=TRUE)==FALSE)

## [1] 0

plot(spydf_states)
```

[image]

Comment: any extra commentary/reading on why the `gBuffer` "hack" works?

Comment: do you want to use gSimplify as it tears down the data.frame and converts the SPDF into spatial polygon object?

Comment: If you're using `sf` you can also use `sf::st_buffer(x, dist = 0)`

Comment: also works in some case when using `PostGIS`

Comment: In `sf` there is a function `st_is_valid(spydf_states)` and a `st_make_valid(spydf_states)`. I tried them and they work great.