# ogr2ogr TopologyException invalid input geometry; ring self-intersection

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, vector, ogr2ogr

I'm facing a problem when using `osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.2.1` [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/gdal/tags) and running these commands on the [Natural Earth vector dataset](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/):

```bsh
# Get and unzip the data 
# (inspired from https://github.com/mapbox/natural-earth-tm2/blob/master/util/setup_db.sh) 
wget -q -N http://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/packages/natural_earth_vector.sqlite.zip
unzip -o -d natural_earth_vector natural_earth_vector.sqlite.zip

# Then, insert data into PG using ogr2ogr:
ogr2ogr \
    -progress \
    -f Postgresql \
    -s_srs EPSG:4326 \
    -t_srs EPSG:3857 \
    -clipsrc -180 -85.05 180.1 85.05 \
    PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mydb user=postgres password=****" \
    -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry \
    -lco OVERWRITE=YES \
    -lco DIM=2 \
    -nlt GEOMETRY \
    -overwrite \
    "natural_earth_vector/packages/natural_earth_vector.sqlite"
```

The PostgreSQL/PostGIS database I'm trying to inject this data into is based on `postgis/postgis:11-3.1`  [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/tags).

This is the error I have:

```bsh
0ERROR 1: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 30.796820538582722 61.704133379158407 at 30.796820538582722 61.704133379158407
```

[This](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/11200897#map=14/30.7978/61.7231) seems to be the culprit watershed in that particular case.

But this error actually appears more than 1'000 thousands times on other geometries    .
I'm not sure where to search for a fix. Any ideas?

If this helps, here is the GDAL version number from inside the container:

```bsh
# ogr2ogr --version
GDAL 3.2.1, released 2020/12/29
```

This thread sounds related but it's from R: [Getting TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid which is due to self-intersection in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163445/getting-topologyexception-input-geom-1-is-invalid-which-is-due-to-self-intersec) and I don't know, if it's the same error, how could I transpose the solution here.

Comment: Have you tried to do a buffer at 0 on all the layer ?

Comment: How would you do that in bash? I cannot figure out some buffering option in ogr2ogr:https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html

Comment: Something like this `ogrinfo natural_earth_vector/packages/natural_earth_vector.sqlite -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE a_sqlite_table SET geometry = ST_BUFFER(geometry, 0)` ?

Comment: I would rather use `ogrinfo natural_earth_vector/packages/natural_earth_vector.sqlite -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE a_sqlite_table SET geometry = ST_MakeValid(geometry)`.

Comment: Do you by chance know from which Debian package I can make use of the ST_MakeValid or any ST_* function within sqlite? I've got plenty of `no such function: ST_MakeValid`.

Comment: even `MakeValid(geometry)` ?

Comment: yep: `no such function: MakeValid` I'm wondering; would it be possible to fix, at the command line, invalid geometries inside a GeoPackage instead of the db.sqlite?

Comment: Test it for sure, a Geopackage is a Spatialite DB, so, spatial functions are inside (IMHO).

Comment: Tested! Same problem; spatial functions doesn't seem embedded in the GPKG file. At least for the that one I'd like to use: `no such function: ST_MakeValid`. I also tried without the `ST_` prefix and: `no such function: MakeValid`.

Comment: GeoPackage is SQLite DB but not SpatiaLite DB. GeoPackage does not have native spatial functions, other than ST_MinX, ST_MinY, ST_MaxX, ST_MaxY, and ST_IsEmpty which are defined in the standard. GDAL adds a couple of functions https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html but for the most part the support of the SpatiaLite functions goes through the SQLite SQL dialect https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html. With SQLite dialect the functions like ST_MakeValid can be used for any datasource.

Comment: Actually, for using SpatiaLite functions against GeoPackages, the right dialect to use is "inderect_sqlite".