# No ST_* spatial functions are available in SQLite3

Tags: gdal, sqlite, docker

I'm [struggling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387902/ogr2ogr-topologyexception-invalid-input-geometry-ring-self-intersection) when using SQLite3 inside a docker container build on this (Ubuntu 20.04 based) GDAL image [`osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.2.1`](https://hub.docker.com/r/osgeo/gdal/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated).

I have to install `sqlite3` first by:

```
# apt-get install -q sqlite
```

it went fine:

```
# sqlite3 --version
3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54 3bfa9cc97da10598521b342961df8f5f68c7388fa117345eeb516eaa837balt1
```

But then, for whatever reason, I'm not able to use any spatial function, e.g.:

```
sqlite> SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(0, 0), 1, 1);
Error: no such function: ST_MakePoint
```

I also tried to install the `spatialite-bin` package, hopping they are hidden in there, but it didn't change anything, even if I entered the following into the SQLite3 command line:

```
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
```

which results in an empty line. And still no ST_* functions.
Same thing after installing these in a last hope:

```
librttopo1 is already the newest version (1.1.0-2).
libspatialite-dev is already the newest version (5.0.0-1).
libspatialite7 is already the newest version (5.0.0-1).
```

How do we get the spatial functions in SQLite3?

Answer (score 2):

You simply did not read the reference doc from Spatialite as I suppose you were expecting portability between PostGIS and Spatialite spatial SQL syntaxes. You are correctly loading your extension but in Spatialite, there is no `ST_MakePoint`
function e.g http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html

You will see that `SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Buffer(MakePoint(0, 0), 1, 1));` does work. For your particular query, `ST_MakePoint` can be replaced with `MakePoint` or `ST_Point`.

**Update:**

As you want in particular functions like ST_MakeValid, you need to build Spatialite with RTTOPO (at least for Spatialite 5.0) support e.g
[image: ST_MakeValid and RTTOPO]

Code for RTTOPO available at https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/rttopo/librttopo

You can find a Docker recipe to build your own spatialite with RTTOPO https://hub.docker.com/r/chrkaatz/node-spatialite/dockerfile

For better understanding of the context, RTTOPO is a replacement for LWGEOM due to https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/tktview/adbde604ba08971a134d02ec6df78789b5c2bfec

Comment: Indeed for the PostGIS background, thanks for the clarifications. But ST_MakePoint was more a placeholder. The function I'm after is `ST_MakeValid(geometry)` which seems to be written as such in sqlite3 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWwAj.png http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html). And which still not available.

Comment: Edited answer ;)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I've read many times that `liblwgeom` was not much appreciated (don't know why) and people struggled compiling sqlite/spatialite with `rttopo` support.... I will give this `apt` package a try then! And will come back here.

Comment: No, installing `librttopo-dev`, `librttopo1` and `libsqlite3-mod-spatialite` in order to `load_extension('mod_spatialite');` was not sufficient. I thought it would be. So, there is probably a moment, in between version 4.3 and version 5.0 where the sqlite3 (or gdal?) devs have incorporated the spatial functions in a more "native" way, I have no other explanations. I strangely but happily didn't not even have to actually _load_ that spatialite module with the working solution I have shown in my answer; sqlite3 is naturally geo-aware in a way! Starting from Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: It's in the Ubuntu packages that changes happened e.g Groovy (20.10) https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/libsqlite3-mod-spatialite vs Focal (20.04) https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libsqlite3-mod-spatialite What is weird is previous versions of Spatialite were supposed to already be able to run `ST_MakeValid` by depending previously on LWGEOM instead of RTTOPO e.g the doc http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html and all your attempts failed...

Answer (score 1):

The ubuntu-small dockerfile is built without SpatiaLite. Use ubuntu-full instead
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/docker/ubuntu-full/Dockerfile

It seems to download libspatialite-dev and libspatialite7.

Comment: I gave it a try without any conviction because, as you said (and also as I printed at the bottom of the question), `libspatialite-dev` and `libspatialite7` in ubuntu-full are at the same versions than the ones I already tested. Therefore, it falls back on the starting point. Still no ST_* functions.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually installing some packages (lowest dependency on top) from the Groovy Gorilla repos:

```
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget \
   proj-bin proj-data gdal-bin sqlite3 libgeos-dev librttopo-dev \
   zlib1g libpq5 libc-bin libc6 libtiff-dev libsqlite3-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev \
&& wget -q http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/proj/proj-data_7.1.0-1_all.deb \
&& wget -q http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/proj/libproj19_7.1.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& wget -q http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/proj/libproj-dev_7.1.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& wget -q http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spatialite/libspatialite7_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& wget -q http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/spatialite/libspatialite-dev_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i proj-data_7.1.0-1_all.deb \
&& dpkg -i libproj19_7.1.0-1_amd64.deb  \
&& dpkg -i libproj-dev_7.1.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libspatialite7_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libspatialite-dev_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& rm --interactive=never proj-data_7.1.0-1_all.deb libproj19_7.1.0-1_amd64.deb \
   libproj-dev_7.1.0-1_amd64.deb libspatialite7_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb libspatialite-dev_5.0.0-1_amd64.deb \
&& apt-get -y autoremove --purge && apt-get -y autoclean && ldconfig \
```

(yes, awful, but working).

My tests where these two function calls, especially the second one:

```
ogrinfo -dialect "SQLite" db.sqlite -sql "SELECT sqlite_version();"
ogrinfo -dialect "SQLite" db.sqlite -sql "SELECT spatialite_version();"
```

Which results in the following when using `osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.2.1`:

```
INFO: Open of `db.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
sqlite_version(): String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  sqlite_version() (String) = 3.31.1
```

and

```
INFO: Open of `db.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
spatialite_version(): String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  spatialite_version() (String) = 4.3.0a
```

respectively. And there, `ST_MakeValid()` was not known.

And it results the following with the workaround shown here above, and using `osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.2.1` (~700MB lighter than the full version):

```
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
INFO: Open of `db.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
sqlite_version(): String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  sqlite_version() (String) = 3.31.1
```

and

```
    - 'VirtualXPath'    [XML Path Language - XPath]
INFO: Open of `db.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
spatialite_version(): String (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  spatialite_version() (String) = 5.0.0
```

respectively. And there, `ST_MakeValid()` was actually available!

It seems these functions where not available with spatialite versions < 5.x. But I'm quite sure I'm wrong somewhere because on the doc, it's written version 4.2 and ST_MakeValid() was already there.

Comment: I tried the Windows version of  spatialite-gui that has SpatiaLite 4.3a and it does have ST_MakeValid. That version is compiled with lwgeom `(select haslwgeom()` returns true).

Comment: And my OSGeo4W installation has SpatiaLite 4.3.0 with lwgeom and ST_MakeValid is there.

Comment: I guess OSGeo people have nicely tight all geo-libraries together and that the GDAL gurus had to make some choices (for any good reasons probably?) about installing older spatialite stuff in their Docker images. I really don't know. From there, we can only hope that they will embed a newest version of spatialite, including support for `rttopo` as well, in the future releases of these GDAL images. But it more sounds like it's a Debian/Ubuntu default packages problem, so a "simple" switch to a base Ubuntu 20.10 image when building the related GDAL images should solve it.